# MySQL SELECT statement for the "length" of the field is greater than 1

Tags: mysql

I have an LINK field in my table. Some rows have a link, some don't.

I'd like to select all rows where LINK is present. (length is greater than X characters).

How do I write this?

Comment: What is a LINK field? Do you mean, some kind of text/varchar field whose name is "LINK"?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(LINK) > 1
```

Here's the [MySql string functions page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) (5.0).

Note that I chose `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of `LENGTH`, as if there are multibyte characters in the data you're probably *really* interested in how many characters there are, not how many bytes of storage they take. So for the above, a row where LINK is a single two-byte character wouldn't be returned - whereas it would when using `LENGTH`.

Note that if `LINK` is `NULL`, the result of `CHAR_LENGTH(LINK)` will be `NULL` as well, so the row won't match.

Answer (score 16):

```
select * from [tbl] where [link] is not null and len([link]) > 1
```

For MySQL user:

```
LENGTH([link]) > 1
```

Comment: The `[identifier]` syntax is used only by MS SQL -- SQL Server and Access (as far as I know). This question is about MySQL.

Comment: I don't think len() is a valid MySql function

Comment: Oh, yeah, I completely missed that part of the question.  Should I delete this answer, as it's not at all relevant?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    CHAR_LENGTH(Link) > x
```

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anybody want to find how in oracle and came here (like me), the syntax is

```
select length(FIELD) from TABLE
```

just in case ;)